# Creating a fully dynamic GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-8, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm currently trying to learn JavaFX and FXML (and Java) and decided to write a textbased RPG. The basis for this was already written quite some time ago, but now I wanted to do the whole thing better. Including the visuals, that is, the GUI.

First of all: I'd like to do this using FXML. That does not mean however that I'm not interested in seeing a way using basic Java.

What I want to build is a fully dynamic GUI. No Matter how it is resized, the components (and ideally the text as well) would be at the same location, relative to the other components / window border.

The window would have some kind of top line with several buttons for saving, the menu, overview and whatnot. Below that, on the left side, would be Character information: Health, Experience, Money etc. On the right side would be the text output (using a Scrollpane) plus a text field, for user input. Below the text input/output I'd place the buttons used for actions and decisions. Bottom left corner does not contain anything, though it should be a separate area.

At first I tried using Splitpanes, not knowing that they can be resized anytime and have visible Dividers. Now I'm not sure what to do.

A Gridpane would give some of the functionality I need (separate the areas), but also does not give the flexibility I want (unless I just don't know how to do it). I couldn't get it to work. So I tried using simple Panels. But with them I couldn't figure out how to keep the panels keep their relative position and size, and how to make the Buttons stick to the borders.

So what would be the best way to go about this? GridPane? Panel? Something else I'm missing? Since I don't really know how to achieve this, any help in any direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: [This article](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm#CHDGHCDG) seems to explain the basic parts about layouts in JavaFX

Comment: Thanks for the links you two. Already read that article. Not all of them though. I'll try using a BorderPane for now, see if I can use a Panel or something to create the bottom-left area.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the [layout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102)?

From your description, it sounds like a [`BorderPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html) might be best for the overall layout (i.e. the root of your scene graph): I'm not quite sure if you could easily make this give you the empty bottom left corner you want. Alternatively you could use a [`GridPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) as you suggested, with appropriate [`ColumnConstraints`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#getColumnConstraints--) and [`RowConstraints`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#getRowConstraints--) applied to size the cells in the pane.